# Setting up custom filters for Microsoft search

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, microsoft-search

I am trying to add filters to the already existing verticals but not getting any option for the existing verticals, but when I add a custom verticals, I am able to add custom filter also.

Is it possible to add a filter for the already existing verticals as in image below
[image]

Also I have added a site column yesterday but still not able to find it in managed properties or crawled properties, any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 2):

Quote from [Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftsearch/custom-filters#important-details):

> Filters can only be added to custom verticals. New filters cannot be
> added to out of the box verticals like All, Files, People, Sites,
> News.